# How to print output twice in Linux?

Tags: linux

Which command is use to print the file name twice on output?

I want to write a pipe that List all the files beginning with the character ‘P’ on the screen twice in succession.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```sh
ls -1 | while read i ; do echo $i $i ; done
```

… should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

```
ls | sed -E 's/^(P.*)/\1 \1/'
```

`ls`, when used with a pipe, puts 1 file per line.

We use `sed` with extended RE support `-E`.

We capture the name of any word beginning with `P`:  `^(P.*)`

and replace it with itself, a space, followed by itself `\1` is a back-reference to what is captured in the parenthesis `( ... )` .

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use the `find` utility:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'P*' -print -print
```

Comment: Nice. If they hadn't talked about pipes that would have been my approach, too =}